# sqlplus to csv scientific number conversion

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus, type-conversion

I have the following in Unix under my shell script:

```
SET linesize 2000
SET pagesize 50000
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF
set numwidth 17
set colsep ","

select accountnum, cardnum, name, address, number from employee;
```

Once it generates the output in .csv, cardnum and accountnum becomes scientific like:

```
5.30706E+15
```

I want it to be:

```
501889176278289
```

I know how to change it in Excel but since I am sending these reports to a client. I want it to go to them in the correct format so they don't have to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(accountnum,'9999999999999999999') accountnum
     , TO_CHAR(cardnum,'9999999999999999999') cardnum
     , name, address, number 
  FROM employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

Except of `TO_CHAR` suggested in other answer you can try:
`set numformat 9999999999999999999` that should solve your problem. 
Another way is `COLUMN accountnum FORMAT 9999999999999999999`